# Get substring from string with the index of the characters

Tags: string, perl, substring

I'm trying to get information from a .txt file:

```
function1(par1, par2)
function2(par1)
function3(par1, par2, par3)
```

I would like to get for example for the first line "function1" as a string, "par1" and "par2" as strings.

I now it is possible to extract a pattern from a string, but I would like to know if it was possible to get a substring using the index of its caracters.

For example as in Python :

```
$function = $row[0:8]
```

would get me "function1"

Thanks,

SLP

Comment: what is it you are trying to get? from what I see you can do the same in perl with substrings...

Comment: I want to separate the string into different substrings. For example I would ideally have "function1" as a string in a variable, "par1" and "par2" in other variables

Comment: If your input has more on each line -- or different lines mixed with the ones you show -- that makes a difference for any approach; please update the question if that is so.  (In my answer I assume that you only need to process lines as shown,)

Answer (score 5):

To parse programming text of a function call, as shown in the sample input

```
my $string = 'function1(par1, par2)';

my ($func_name, @params) = split /\s*\(\s*|\s*,\s*|\s*\)/, $string;
```

where [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) builtin uses a regex for the separator pattern, and we tell it to break up the string by either `(` or `,` or `)` (I also include the closing parenthesis so that the last element wouldn't be stuck with it).  The regex pattern also has possible spaces sprinkled around.

If your `.txt` file has literally lines like what you show then you can simply apply the above to each line.  If there is more on each line though then you'd need to preprocess that first (or use a different approach); please show the realistic input if lines have more than what is shown.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the same behaviour as your Python example, the [`substr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function will do what you want.

The code:

```perl
my $a = "function1(par1, par2)";
print substr $a, 0, 8
```

produces "function" as the output

Per your comment "I want to separate the string into different substrings", if you have a variable number and length of function parameters, a regular expression is by far the best way to do this.

```perl
while (<>) {
  if (/^([^\(]*)\(([^\)]*)\)/) {
    my $f=$1;
    my @params=split ",", $2;
    print "Function: $f, Params: @params\n";
  }
}
```

Given the input

```
function1(par1, par2)
function2(par1)
function3(par1, par2, par3)
```

This code will print

```
Function: function1, Params: par1  par2
Function: function2, Params: par1
Function: function3, Params: par1  par2  par3
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I had already tried this but I must have had a mistake somewhere because it didn't produce the result expected.