# Perl - Problem with "]" in a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string :

```
my $string = "name_of_my_function(arg1,arg2,[arg3,arg4])";
```

and I want to extract the name of the function "name_of_my_function" and the parameters :

```
$arg1 = "arg1"
$arg2 = "arg2"
@arg_list = ("arg3", "arg4")
```

the code I use to extract the function is :

```
$row =~ m/^([^\(]*)\(([^\)]*)\)/;
$function = $1;
```

However, it works when the string doesn't have any `"]"`, for example :

```
my $string = "name_of_my_function(arg1,arg2,arg3)";
```

but it doesn't return anything when there is a `"]"`

Any idea?

Thanks,

SLP

Comment: "_but it doesn't return anything_"  -- the regex you show doesn't care about any specific characters other than parens; it should capture the function name and all of arguments with or without `[]`.  Then you can parse the arguments in the next step, which is what I would recommend (instead of a single monster regex)

Comment: @zdim I wanted to do so, but for the lines where the string contains a "[" or "]", there is no match. Also more surprising, when there is only "[" or "]", the match is ok, but when there are both of them I don't get any match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you show captures the function name, and all other arguments in a string, which is a very reasonble first step.  Then parse the arguments out of that second string.  I expand your `$string` so to have multiple bracketed lists of arguments, interleaved with non-bracketed ones

```
perl -wE'
    $s = "name_of_my_function(arg1,arg2,[arg3,arg4],arg5,[arg6,arg7])"; 
    @m = $s =~ /^([^\(]*)\(([^\)]*)\)/; 
    @p = grep { $_ } split /\s*,\s*|\[(.*?)\]/, $m[1];
    for (@p) { 
        if (/,/) { push @arg_list, $_ }
        else     { push @args, $_ }
    }
    say $m[0];
    say for @args; 
    say for @arg_list
'
```

This prints

```
name_of_my_function
arg1
arg2
arg5
arg3,arg4
arg6,arg7
```

The `split` is where individual arguments are extracted, as well as bracketed argument list(s), each as a string.  That may return empty elements thus `grep { $_ }` to filter them out.

Then you can proceed to extract individual arguments from lists that were in brackets, by splitting each string in `@arg_list` by `,` again.

---

The main part of the above *can*, as the problem stands, go in one statement

```
@p = grep { $_ } split /\( | \) | \[(.*?)\] |,/x, $s;
```

where I added `/x` modifier so to be able to space it out for readability. This delivers to `@p` the function name, individual arguments, and a string with (comma separated) argument list from each `[]`.

However, I think that it is far more sensible to break this up into several steps.

Comment: array @m can be obtained using ````@m = split(/\)|\(/,$s);```` also right?.

Comment: @stack0114106  Yes, like `@p` is done at the end.  I used regex for no particular reason (I used that `split` [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54931693/4653379)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the number of arguments is variable, that is not that simple to do it with rgex only (arguments will be matched with `+` quantifier, so they won't be stored in capturing group, which would be easy to extract). Having in mind the above, you could use this pattern `(\w+)\(((\w+|\[(\w+,?)+\]),?)+\)`

Explanation:

`(\w+)` - match one or more word characters (name of a function) and store it in first capturing group,

`(\w+|\[(\w+,?)+\])` - alternation: match `\w+` (same as above) or `\[(\w+,?)+\]`: `\[` - match `[` literally, `(\w+,?)+` - match on or more times `\w+,` pattern which is one or more word characters followed by one or zero commas (`,?`), `\]` - match `]` literally,

`((\w+|\[(\w+,?)+\]),?)+` - match whole above pattern, optionally followed by comma (`,?`) one or more times. This would match argument list.

`\(`, `\)` 0 match `(`, `)` literally

Further processing - extract whats between brackets `()` in order to extract arguments list programatically - it would be easier that doing it with complex regular expression

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wBcJZ0/2)

**UPDATE**:

Try pattern: `https://regex101.com/r/wBcJZ0/3`

I omitted explanation, as it is very similair to previous pattern.

[Updted demo](https://regex101.com/r/wBcJZ0/3)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is very clear. However I should have given more details : my $string syntaxes can be various : name_of_my_function(arg1,arg2,arg3) or name_of_my_function(arg1,arg2,[arg3,arg4]) or name_of_my_function("arg1"). Also the arguments can be strings or numerical (double or integer)... So your solution doesn't work for me, but I should have been clearer sorry